# Where JDBC resultSet is stored?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, resultset

I need to process millions of records. I am using JDBC (with Oracle driver) with fetchSize to get the records in batches from DB.
As per Oracle documentation, the select query is executed only once and round trips to DB is made based on fetch size set. So I understand that all the rows are not completed loaded into application server. This make sense and I am not worried about memory usage from application side.
But what I want to understand is how does Oracle stores the rows in resultSet in Oracle DB Server if it is executing the select query only once -

1. does it creates a temp table and stores the resultSet?
2. does it uses some mechanism which does not utilises any extra memory at DB server side?

   ```
    val conn: Connection = datasource.connection
    var stmt: PreparedStatement? = null
    var resultSet: ResultSet? = null
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select query")
        stmt.fetchSize = 1000
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery() 
        // does above line load all the rows of resultSet in a 
        // temp memory in DB or uses actual memory where actual 
        // data is stored in Oracle DB ?
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // do some operation
           }
        }
    finally {
        // close resultSet, statement, connection
    }
   ```

I want to understand this from Oracle server side and not from application side. My logic goes to Oracle storing the resultSet data somewhere internally but I don't find any official documentation to support it. My application design will depend on how this actually behaves.

Comment: At a minimum this will take memory on the database server in the buffer cache (raw data) and the related session's server process (cursor information). This will definitely take memory from your DB server, and if you don't page through things fast enough it is possible that data may be rotated out of the cache, or that the DB won't be able to keep a logically consistent view of it long enough. If you are doing something *to* the data on that scale (not just presenting), better to handle it within the DB if possible, using a stored procedure: avoid network and app server latency.

Comment: A result set is an internal pointer to a memory address on the database server where the database stores information about the query the cursor it is executing and the current progress of the cursor. The database does not need to store the entire result set at the cursor pointer as it can retrieve the data from the data files and the log files for the given point in time when the cursor was executed. It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve but if you are going to try to access the same memory location to retrieve the result set then don't do that (and trying that is not documented).

Comment: Thanks @MT0, that answers my question but do you have any official documentation link for reference.  I have updated my question with code sample for reference.

Comment: This is described in the Database Concepts documentation: [Overview of SQL processing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/sql.html#GUID-0E8DFE97-F2DD-4183-8A4B-1EA9087E9E37) and [Memory architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/memory-architecture.html#GUID-913335DF-050A-479A-A653-68A064DCCA41)